# why does this give me an error saying unexpected symbol ´1´ in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: unity-game-engine

i making a game and this popped up in unity

i looked from other places and didnt find the answer

```cs
sing UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class pyssy : MonoBehaviour {

    public int bulletsPerMag = 30;
    public int bulletsLeft;

    public float fireRate = 0,1f;

    float fireTimer;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
            Fire();
        }

        if (fireTimer < fireRate)
            fireTimer += Time.deltaTime;
    
    }

    private void Fire()
    {
        if (fireTimer < fireRate) return;
        Debug.Log("shot!")
    }
}
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

`public float fireRate = 0,1f;` You should use dots instead of commas for float values. Commas in programming are used to seperate different values.

Change it to `public float fireRate = 0.1f;`

And to give you a tip. When you get an `unexpected symbol/character` error or something along the lines of that, it usually means it's either a typo or a line that was not ended correctly. At least that's been the case for me some times!

Comment: yea i did now its sayin Unexpected symbol `}`

Comment: Haha, see that's what I meant. You forgot a semicolon at `Debug.Log("shot!")`

Comment: No problem! Make sure to select the answer as the correct one, so other's will know your problem is solved!